# target="_blank" is not working in firefox?

Tags: firefox, target

target="_blank" is not working with firefox
`<a href="login.php" target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.close();" > <img src="images/loginto-apply-but.gif" border="0"/> </a>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below instead.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('login.php','_blank');window.close();return false">
  <img src="images/loginto-apply-but.gif" border="0"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not working because you're calling a Javascript event to close the current window and after launching the "_blank" to acces to your link. You have to create a Js method to launch your link and after close the current window.

Comment: what would be the js for that to open the login page in new window and closing the current window

Comment: After reading some FAQ on FF, the window.close() doesn't work on this browser. If you want to close your past page and open a new to cut the history you would use self.location.replace("url");