# Target="_blank" working local but not online (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

My hyperlinks which have the target='_blank' are opening the requested url to open in a new window, but ONLY when I'm working local.

Once I put my website online, they won't open in a new window. Does anyone knows a solution?

http://www.feestpaleis.be -> quick example: the social media icons should open in a new window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Target "\_blank" not opening new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559765/target-blank-not-opening-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;"`

Comment: It works for 50% now, it opens in a new window, but it also opens in the same window :\

Comment: The HTML code for the links is just fine. However, the browser does not seem to honor these, because some JS on the page (from plugin or theme) is preventing it.
When visiting the site with JS turned off in the browser, everything works as expected, which confirms my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

how about use this jquery? maybe it will help you..

```
jQuery('a[target=_blank]').click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank'); 
});
```