# HTML a href without target is not working

Tags: html

On a website I made, I had a link with target="_blank". A lot of users complained that the link was not working, especially on mobile devices, mostly iOS.
I changed the link, by removing the target, but now I still got complains that the link is not working, only when the user opens it in a new tab.

On all my devices (multiple pc's, android tablet en phone) it is working.

How do I fix this? Do the users have to clear their cache?
How can I prevent this in the future? Is _blank not used for mobile browsers?

The link as it is in the website:

```
<li class="last"><a href="http://www.blabla.nl/login/login.php" target="_blank" class="animate">login</a></li>

.animate,
.animate:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code ???

Comment: Can it be that actually they say that "it doesn't work" cause on mobile the target _blank link opens another tab, but the opened tab is not in focus, so basically it is open in background and according to them it doesn't work as they cannot see anything...Try having a look on how IOS browser tab works maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the target attribute is correct, but browsers need not honor it. They may interpret it as opening the destination in a new tab rather than new window, or they may completely ignore the attribute. Browsers have settings for such issues. Moreover, opening of new windows may be prevented by browser plugins (typically designed to prevent annoying advertisements).

There’s little you can do about this as an author. You might consider opening a new window with JavaScript instead, cf. to the accepted answer to [target="_blank" is not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454382/target-blank-is-not-working-in-firefox/12454474#12454474)?, but browsers may be even more reluctant to let pages open new windows that way than via target

Source [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16560040/3164682)

Answer (score 0):

May be this is because pop blocker enabled on their device browser. I will suggest you to try out following code for your links.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('Popover.aspx','_blank');" >Click Me!!</a>
```

OR

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.open('Popover.aspx','_blank');" >Click Me!!</a>
```

Let see whether it will help you or not. Hope so it must work.