# link with target="_blank" does not open in new tab in Chrome

Tags: html, hyperlink

On [this website](http://www.eventbuddies.com.au/), the top accordion navigation contains an element called "Foundation": [(screenshot)](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/screenshots/eventbuddies.jpg).

This element is produced by HTML code:

```
<a href="http://www.foracure.org.au" target="_blank" style="width: 105px;"></a>
```

However, in Chrome, when you click on this element, the new website does not open in a new tab.

Can you please tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: Works for me as expected, the target is opened in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. I edited the question to indicate the problem occurs in Chrome.

Comment: I am using a chromium browser. Works for me. So apparently it is an effect of whatever google adds to the fine chromium browser for its chrome version.

Answer (score 37):

```
Replace 

<a href="http://www.foracure.org.au" target="_blank"></a>    

with 

<a href="#" onclick='window.open("http://www.foracure.org.au");return false;'></a>
```

in your code and will work in Chrome and other browsers.

Thanks
Anurag

Comment: This will work.  However as mentioned by Jack, this will break if javascript isn't supported.  MDN suggests to never use this and gives several reasons.  Hope this helps:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Never_use_this_form_of_code_for_links_%3Ca_hrefjavascriptwindow.open(...)_...%3E

Comment: This is not a good replacement as this might hinder crawling of these links

Comment: unfortunately not work in app browser instagram =(

Comment: JS does not work with emails so if this code is in email it is not good

Comment: Thank you so much @Anurag. You literally saved my life! :)

Answer (score 25):

Because JavaScript is handling the click event. When you click, the following code is called:

```js
el.addEvent('click', function(e){
    if(obj.options.onOpen){
        new Event(e).stop();
        if(obj.options.open == i){
            obj.options.open = null;
            obj.options.onClose(this.href, i);
        }else{
            obj.options.open = i;
            obj.options.onOpen(this.href, i);
        }   
    }       
})
```

The `onOpen` manually changes the `location`.

Edit: Regarding your comment...
If you can modify ImageMenu.js, you could update the script which calls `onClose` to pass the `a` element object (`this`, rather than `this.href`)

```js
obj.options.onClose(this, i);
```

Then update your ImageMenu instance, with the following `onOpen` change:

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var myMenu = new ImageMenu($$('#imageMenu a'), {
        openWidth: 310,
        border: 2,
        onOpen: function(e, i) {
            if (e.target === '_blank') {
                window.open(e.href);    
            } else {
                location = e.href;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This would check for the target property of the element to see if it's `_blank`, and then call `window.open`, if found.

If you'd prefer not to modify ImageMenu.js, another option would be to modify your links to identify them in your `onOpen` handler. Say something like:

```js
<a href="http://www.foracure.org.au/#_b=1" target="_blank" style="width: 105px;"></a>
```

Then, update your `onOpen` call to:

```js
onOpen: function(e, i) {
    if (e.indexOf('_b=1') > -1) {
        window.open(e);   
    } else {
        location = e;
    }
}
```

The only downside to this is the user sees the hash on hover.

Finally, if the number of links that you plan to open in a new window are low, you could create a map and check against that. Something like:

```js
var linksThatOpenInANewWindow = {
    'http://www.foracure.org.au': 1
};

onOpen: function(e, i) {
    if (linksThatOpenInANewWindow[e] === 1) {
        window.open(e);   
    } else {
        location = e
    }
}
```

The only downside is maintenance, depending on the number of links.

Others have suggested modifying the link (using `#` or `javascript:`) and adding an inline event handler (`onclick`) - I don't recommend that at all as it breaks links when JS is disabled/not supported.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Is it possible to edit this JavaScript to open the link in a new tab? If so, how?

Comment: Hey @Steve - I edited my answer to include some work arounds. Hope they help! :)

Answer (score 8):

Learn from another guy:

```html
<a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" href="http://www.foracure.org.au">Some Other Site</a>
```

It makes sense to me.

Comment: Thx, it works for me your solution. Feel free to thank the other guy ;)

Answer (score 7):

For Some reason it is not working so we can do this by another way

just remove the line and add this :-

```
<a onclick="window.open ('http://www.foracure.org.au', ''); return false" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

According to this article [How to fix target=”_blank” links: a security and performance issue in web pages](https://medium.com/sedeo/how-to-fix-target-blank-a-security-and-performance-issue-in-web-pages-2118eba1ce2f) this is due to security issue.
Try adding `rel=”noopener noreferrer”` to your  tag, or try this JavaScript:

```js
let link = window.open(url, "_blank");
link.opener = null;
```

Comment: I tried this in my circumstance and it didnt change the link from redirecting instead of opening in a new tab. is there a way to check if this issue is causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem for me.

Fixed it by putting `target="_blank"` before `href`

```html
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Example</a>
```

Comment: This works for me with React app.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the target attribute is correct, but browsers need not honor it. They may interpret it as opening the destination in a new tab rather than new window, or they may completely ignore the attribute. Browsers have settings for such issues. Moreover, opening of new windows may be prevented by browser plugins (typically designed to prevent annoying advertisements).

There’s little you can do about this as an author. You might consider opening a new window with JavaScript instead, cf. to the accepted answer to target="_blank" is not working in firefox?, but browsers may be even more reluctant to let pages open new windows that way than via target.

[target="_blank" is not working in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454382/target-blank-is-not-working-in-firefox/12454474#12454474)

Comment: The referenced link is not that **target="_blank"** is not working in Firefox, but that this one situation in which the OP tried to close a window using an unsupported (by Firefox) call.  The link has nothing to do with this OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The better option is

```html
<a href="http://www.foracure.org.au" target="frameName" style="width: 105px;"></a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the only solution (not using javascript) that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked uses wordpress and the Javascript library
sliding door imageMenu
in ImageMenu.js this bit of code adds a click event to the anchor tag

```
el.addEvent('click', function(e){

    if(obj.options.onOpen){
        new Event(e).stop();
        if(obj.options.open == i){
            obj.options.open = null;
            obj.options.onClose(this.href, i);
        }else{
            obj.options.open = i;
            obj.options.onOpen(this.href, i);
        }           
    }           
})
```

the part it stops the event probably overwrites the default behaviour of clicking the anchor tag which would be handled by the browser.
I think the default reason for this is that the "sliding door" is supposed to shut when clicked instead of linking to an external site.
often navigation menus contain anchor tags with hyperlinks and if the href was not set to # then it would reload the page instead of opening or closing the "sliding door"
similar to a burger menu

Answer (score 0):

If you code a link like this:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_WORD" rel="noreferrer">`

It will open in a new browser tab.

You can use pretty much any word prefaced with an underscore character. Just don't use "_blank"

Problem 100% solved!

Answer (score 0):

This has been created by the same smart people who invented the "allow cookies" thingy. Simply doing "window.open()" with "preventDefault()" doesn't work anymore - the URL opens a new tab and still redirects the current tab. So, I have come up with a solution where you just make the current tab open do somethink like a reload. Not an elegant solution, but it works:

HTML:

```
<a href="/someurl" target="_blank">Some text</a>
```

JQuery

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').click(function(e){
        
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href,'_blank');
    location.href = location.href;
    return false;
        
});
```

You could do `location.reload();` instead of `location.href = location.href;`, it's just that in my particular case reload adds additional load.

Answer (score -3):

most simple answer

```
<a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return false;" href="http://www.foracure.org.au">Some Other Site</a>
```

it will work

Comment: how could inverting the attributes make a difference?

Comment: what make it difference bro? cause I see nothing happing when we change position of their attributes

Answer (score -4):

If you use React this should work:

```js
<a href="#" onClick={()=>window.open("https://...")}</a>
```

Comment: The OP was asking specifically about the the behavior of target ="_blank" setting of the link element.  Introducing React (or any Javascript) is not super relevant to the question.