# anchor tag is not working on image hover effect

Tags: html, css

anchor tag with link href is now working in not showing clickable

```css
/****** PLACE YOUR CUSTOM STYLES HERE ******/

.gridpb {
    padding-bottom: 24px
}

.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" /></filter></svg>#filter');
  filter: grayscale(1) blur(3px);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) blur(3px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}

.hovereffect a.info, .hovereffect h2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
  transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info, .hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-sm-4 gridpb">
                     <div class="hovereffect">
                     <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" />
                     <div class="overlay">
                     <h2>Scientific Funk - 1988 EP</h2>
                <a class="info" href="https://www.beatport.com/release/1988-ep/1577944" target="_blank" >Buy on Beatport</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

anchor tag with link href is now working in not showing clickable

```
<div class="col-sm-4 gridpb">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img src="img/8.jpg" />
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2>Scientific Funk - 1988 EP</h2>
      <a class="info" href="https://www.beatport.com/release/1988-ep/1577944" target="_blank">Buy on Beatport</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

anchor tag is correctly working outside the hover effect but not inside and i want inside

Comment: the button BUY ON BEATPORT has link with anchor tag but it not pointing to link which is given in the anchor tag

Comment: @hasni Are you receiving a "Mixed Content" warning message in your console after clicking the button?

Comment: actually it is not clickable on my side and i am not receiving ay warning in console

Comment: if we put this anchor tag outside the hove effect div it is working

Comment: @hasni Strange.. I have copied exactly your code to jsfiddle and it seems worked: https://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/fzjq47ba/

Comment: but it is not working on my end i have copied to

Comment: I've [raised this weird issue with StackSnippets on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325572/why-does-target-blank-break-links-in-snippets).

Answer (score 0):

In your problem 
if you remove target ="_blank" then it's working sucessfully

problem is that target="_blank" not working if you want help for that then refure this link
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444051/link-with-target-blank-does-not-open-in-new-tab-in-chrome)

i hope it's helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not an issue with your code. A stackoverflow code snippet is a iframe running within this page which prevents opening a new parent window in your browser. I just copied your code to this JSFiddle which is working fine!

Just look at your code in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lprajus2007/q0on2Lxs/1/) on my JSFiddle.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 gridpb">
                 <div class="hovereffect">
                 <img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" />
                 <div class="overlay">
                 <h2>Scientific Funk - 1988 EP</h2>
            <a class="info" href="https://www.beatport.com/release/1988-ep/1577944" target="_blank" >Buy on Beatport</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```