# target _blank in HTML::a not working yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I am using below peice of code.

```
[
            'attribute' => 'Application',
            'format' => 'html',
            'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
                $student_username = $dataProvider->student_username;
                return Html::a('Print', Url::toRoute(['/coordinatorpanel/print-form', 'student_username' => $student_username]),
                    ['target' => '_blank', 'class' => 'btn btn-success center-block']);
            },
        ]
```

**HTML OUTPUT :**

```
<a class="btn btn-success center-block" href="/nse/frontend/web/index.php?r=coordinatorpanel%2Fprint-form&amp;student_username=COR39690113" target="_blank">
```

But, when I click on the link, I am not navigated to new tab, the request is processed in same Tab. I tried this on both 'Mozilla' and 'Chrome'.

Any help would be deeply rewared :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go other way round to run code properly.

[You can click here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444051/link-with-target-blank-does-not-open-in-new-tab-in-chrome)

Below is the piece of code that I modified and worked for me. I had to set 'onclick' event and set href as empty.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'Application',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
        $student_username = $dataProvider->student_username;
        return Html::a('Print', '',
            ['onclick' => "window.open ('".Url::toRoute(['/coordinatorpanel/print-form', 
                          'student_username' => $student_username])."'); return false", 
             'class' => 'btn btn-success center-block']);
    },
],
```

Answer (score 18):

Disable Pjax in gridview. In my case I wanted to display an image in a new window and it was coming up as garbled characters in the grid instead.

```
'format' => "raw",
'value' => function ($d) {
     return Html::a($d->image_filename, '/'.$d->imagePath(),['target'=>'_blank', 'data-pjax'=>"0"] );
    },
```

ps. be mindful of XSS using raw format

Comment: For GridView using Pjax, this is the simplest answer, i.e. `['data-pjax' => 0, 'target' => '_blank']`. The `'format' => "raw",` shouldn't even be necessary in most cases.

Comment: Spot on @RichHarding

Answer (score 10):

Try to change your code like below

```
[
        'attribute' => 'Application',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($dataProvider) {
            $student_username = $dataProvider->student_username;
            return Html::a('Print', Url::toRoute(['/coordinatorpanel/print-form', 'student_username' => $student_username]),
                ['target' => '_blank', 'class' => 'btn btn-success center-block']);
        },
    ]
```

Here it used `'format' => 'raw'` to avoid formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this code is inside some widget that formats output because this is common case. If so just change format to `raw`.

Comment: I changed it but it is still the same. I haveupdated the code

Comment: It doesn't work with `'format' => 'raw'`? Check source if the link tag has been generated properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the above code with HTML output for link tag by setting Format to 'raw'. But still no positive effect.

Comment: This will not work if the rest of a widget is using Pjax. In that case you simply have to use: `['data-pjax' => 0, 'target' => '_blank']`

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, it's also working perfectly -

The problem may also be in `pjax`. even if you use the `row` format.

In this case just add `linkSelector` param:

```
\yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(
    ['id' => 'samle', 'linkSelector' => 'a:not(.target-blank)']
);
```

and add corresponding css class to your links:

```
return Html::a(
    'Print',
    ['/site/print', 'id' => $model->id],
    ['target'=>'_blank', 'class' => 'target-blank']
);
```

This will prevent only these links from `pjax` so they can be open in new tab.