# Is it possible to achieve native multi tab PWA within the same browser window?

Tags: php, ajax, browser, progressive-web-apps

I have built a web application for a client in **PHP**. And I implemented a `PWA (Progressive Web App)` app for this web app, which is working quite well.

But recently my client asked me to add window tabs for this **PWA application**. But the problem is i already finished this job, and i do not want to re-build my architecture from scratch.

I would like it so that (if possible) when the user clicks a link, the page opens in the same app as it is right now, but in a new tab.

When i add `target="_blank"` to my links, like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a target="_blank" class="nav-link raporlarSol" href="/app/bankadurumlari"><i class="material-icons">euro_symbol</i>
    <span>Banka Durumları</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

the page opens outside PWA window in a new android browser. Which is not a behaviour he accepts.

I have searched the web, but i haven't been able to find a proper answer. There is link [here](https://vaadin.com/pwa/learn/multi-page-pwa) which didn't help me at all.

I know that i can do it with `PHP Sessions` and `AJAX`, but this means a lot of work to do.

I want to achieve this natively but do not know if possible.

I appreciate if you share your thoughts on this.

Comment: There are a number of answers in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444051/link-with-target-blank-does-not-open-in-new-tab-in-chrome). Maybe one of them could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the case. It is a Progressive Web App issue. But i think i found a workaround. I'm going to post it when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are facing the same issue here is what i did:

I didn't change anything on my current architecture. But created a new blank page with Bootstrap Navs created dynamically like so:

```
$('.add-raporsayfasi').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linki = $(this).data('linki');
    var ismi = $(this).text();
    var id = $("#raporTabContainer .nav-item").children().length;
    var tabId = 'raporsayfasi_' + id;
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link raportablink" id="raporsayfasi-tab_' + id + '" data-toggle="tab" href="#raporsayfasi_' + id + '">'+ismi+'</a></li>');
    $('#raporTabContainerContent').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"></div>');
   $('#'+tabId).load( linki );
   $(this).addClass('disabled').removeClass('add-raporsayfasi');
   $(this).remove();
   addSwipeTo(".nav-item");
   $('#raporsayfasi-tab_'+id).tab('show');
});
```

And changed my current navigation to :

```
<a class="nav-link add-raporsayfasi" data-linki="/app/bankadurumlari" id="ekle" href="#">Banka Durumları</a>
```

Thw jquery code takes the `data-linki` attribute and loads the page using jQuery's `load()` function like so:

```
$('#'+tabId).load( linki );
```

Hope it helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your requirements are, but 3 solutions are floating in my head.

remove target="_blank" that always opens a new browser window/tab. If you launched form the homescreen the user agent interprets that as a new window, outside the PWA application context.

** side note: when using target="_blank" always use rel="noopener" too ;)

If you want to lunch with the browser chrome, not full screen, you can open a sibling browser tab and it won't launch the browser from the PWA since the PWA is already within the browser's execution context.

If by tab you mean a tabbed UI then you can just create that UI. It is pretty basic, a series of sibling divs with click event handlers to toggle the visible tab content. In this context the problem more a responsive design problem than a PWA problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and kind advice. But the main problem was that i didn't want to move from MPA to SPA, because of the current structure of the main classes such as routing and authentication on the Server-Side. But finally i managed to solve my problem, and i'm going to post it here asap.

Comment: Not sure what MPA refers to.
But progressive web app does not mean single page application FWIW :)
https://love2dev.com/blog/pwa-spa/
It is a common misconception.
Glad you found a solution!

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/  -- appears you no longer need to specify noopener assuming you don't support old browsers.   Interesting read on how things get hacked.